# Are there any problems with Householder transformation returning zeroes on diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I'm using a Householder routine to numerically diagonalize nx2n matrices. The resulting diagonalized matrices are then used in an eigenmode process, which will occasionally just produce "noise". I've noticed that in these cases, the Householder routine is returning matrices which possess some zero values on the diagonal entries, e.g.:

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}a&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\0&b&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\0&0&c&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&d&*&*&*&*&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&0&0&0&*&*&*&*&*&*\\0&0&0&0&0&0&*&*&*&*&*&*\end{bmatrix}$$

Is there anything inappropriate about this type of this solution resulting from using Householder's routine? If so, does this form (with the zero entries on the diagonal) suggest anything about the original matrix?

Comment: I'm not clear what you are looking for from the row reduction by Householder transformations.  The nonsquare matrix won't have eigenvalues per se.  Perhaps singular values are sought?

Comment: I should have clarified that I do some processing to the matrix first before seeking eigenvalues. However, that's not terribly related to the question, I am just suspicious that the incorrect eigenvalues and form of the diagonalized matrix are related. I would have expected to see all non-zero entries on the diagonal -- which is the case when the correct eigenvalues are later found.

Comment: I would be suspicious as well, but I don't know what eigenvalues are meant, so I can't articulate what is going wrong.  Perhaps column exchanges would get you what you want,  but that's a shot in the dark.

Comment: You must have a mistake unless the vector you are transforming has zero length.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for the reply -- are you saying that the Householder routine is mistaken in this case?

Comment: Since I have no idea what routine you are using I cannot make that claim, but the Householder transformation is orthogonal it preserves length, so if you map a partial column into a zero vector then the source must be a zero vector.